# Numbers larger than long long

Tags: c++, c++11, long-integer

I am writing a C++ program to generate the series of Fibonacci numbers. This is the 1, 1, 2, 3, 5... series. The 300th number in this series is 359579325206583560961765665172189099052367214309267232255589801. This is well beyond the limits of `int` or even `unsigned long long`. How can I continue to represent such large numbers?

Here's my code:

```
unsigned long long FibLoop(int n)
{
    // Keep track of previous two numbers
    unsigned long long prev[2];
    prev[0] = 1;
    prev[1] = 1;

    // Loop
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        prev[i % 2] = prev[0] + prev[1];
        cout << i << "\t" << prev[i % 2] << endl;
    }

    // Return
    return prev[n % 2];
}
```

Comment: Use a *Big Number* library.  Search [softwarerecs.se] for "c++ big number library".

Comment: You'll need a big number library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: For that in particular, if you have a 256- or 512-bit integer available (probably in SSE4 or AVX extensions, if you’re compiling for x64), you can use that. Those will only last so long, though, because Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially. At some point you do need a bignum library, as others pointed out.

Comment: Also, there is a [closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) way of calculating Fibonacci numbers (and the section after that gives another way to calculate them which might be better for computers), but that would also require a bignum library because most `long double`s don’t have enough bits of precision (and even [octuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format) won’t go much farther).

Comment: @vasek Cousin of Bruno Bianchi, creator of inspector Gadget.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download from external libraries such as  [BoostMultiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: You *could* write your own, but using an existing one is probably a better idea unless this is an academic exercise. Which it may well be, but if so the focus doesn’t seem to be bignums.